# Deciding Propositional Intuitionistic Logic by Propositional classiscal logic methods.

Tags: logic

I read about the double negation translation (Glivenkos Translation). My question is could i somehow apply this Theorem backwards to obtain a decision algorithm for an intuitionstic logic formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open problem, but most people don't believe so. The reasons are complexity-theoretic.

Deciding whether a formula is a tautology of intuitionistic propositional logic (or even its $\rightarrow$-only fragment)  is known to be a [**PSPACE**-complete](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00153-003-0179-x) problem.

**PSPACE** is the complexity class of all decision problems that a Turing machine can solve using a polynomial amount of space (as a function of the size of the input). **PSPACE**-completeness means that a method for deciding whether a formula of intuitionistic propositional logic is a tautology could easily be used to solve any other problem in the class **PSPACE** (for a precise definition of the word "*easily*").

Meanwhile, deciding whether a formula is a tautology of classical propositional logic  is known to be **coNP**-complete. We know that **coNP** is a subclass of **PSPACE**.

If the double-negation translation provided an effective decision algorithm for the intuitionistic logic tautology problem, that would reduce a **PSPACE**-complete problem to a problem in **coNP**, that would prove **coNP** = **PSPACE**. Is **coNP** = **PSPACE**? Most people believe that **coNP** is a proper subclass of **PSPACE**, but nobody knows for sure. This is one of the open problems in complexity theory (you may have heard about its more famous cousin, **P**=?**NP**).

Comment: What about an inefficient translation from IL to CL? Making the formula exponentially longer, does such a thing exist ?

Comment: I suppose the answer will depend on how you define "translation". There are many maps $f: \text{IPC-Formula} \rightarrow \text{CPC-Formula}$ such that $\text{IPC-tautology} = \text{CPC-tautology} \circ f$, but most hardly count as translations.

Comment: Yes that is what im looking for. Can you give me examples of such ?

Comment: Consider the map $f$ with $f(x) = A \rightarrow A$ if $x$ is an IPC-tautology, and $f(x) = (A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A$ otherwise.

No reasonable person would call $f$ as a translation. But that leaves you with the problem of defining "translation".

If you're asking "is there a *well-known*, explored-in-the-literature translation with this property", the answer is almost certainly no. The uses of such a process would be fairly limited, so it's unlikely to be explored.

Comment: You can probably construct something that looks like a translation by proving a result on Kripke models along the lines of "if a formula of length measure m is not an IPC-tautology, then it fails in some finite Kripke counter-model of size at most f(m)", and then mapping a formula $P$ of measure m to a CPC-sentence expressing that $P$ holds in all Kripke structures of size at most f(m).